# Display a UIView within a UITableViewCell pragmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitableview

I am using the following code to instance a `UIView` from a `XIB` and then add it to the selected `UITableViewCell` for displaying. When I run the code and touch the cell, I can walk through the code and see that everything is instanced correctly (nothing is nil) and yet the view is never displayed.

I have a UIView with a couple of buttons on it. In Interface Builder I set the UIView to use a sub-class of UIView which at the moment does not have any code in it, other than the boiler plate generated by Xcode. I'm hoping someone can point out any obvious errors I've made in using this code to get this to work.

Please note that at one point I had the UIView showing within the UITalbeViewCell, but I had messed some stuff up during some refactoring and ended up re-writing the code to handle this. When that happened, I could no longer display the UIView within the cell.

```
@implementation HZRunwayViewController
{
    EKEvent *currentEvent;
    BOOL editingEvent;
    HZEventDrawerView *eventDrawer;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Check if we are touching an event
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && [self.eventsForCurrentDay count]) {

        // Grab the selected cell and make sure it's an event cell
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if ([cell isKindOfClass:[HZEventTableViewCell class]]) {

            // Setup our event cell and our action drawer for use.
            HZEventTableViewCell *eventCell = (HZEventTableViewCell *)cell;

            if (!eventDrawer) {
                eventDrawer = (HZEventDrawerView *)[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HZEventDrawerView" owner:self options:nil][0];
            }

            eventDrawer.bounds = eventCell.bounds;
            NSLog(@"X:%f  Y:%f  Width: %f  Height: %f", eventDrawer.bounds.origin.x, eventDrawer.bounds.origin.y, eventDrawer.bounds.size.width, eventDrawer.bounds.size.height);
            [eventCell.contentView addSubview:eventDrawer];
            [eventCell bringSubviewToFront:eventDrawer];
            eventDrawer.hidden = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

***Update***

In order to test and see if it was my XIB file or sub-class causing the issue, I stopped using it, instanced a UIView, added a UIButton to it and then added it to the Cell.contentView subview. When I touch the cell, nothing happens.

```
// Grab the selected cell and make sure it's an event cell
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if ([cell isKindOfClass:[HZEventTableViewCell class]]) {

            // Setup our event cell and our action drawer for use.
            HZEventTableViewCell *eventCell = (HZEventTableViewCell *)cell;

            if (!eventDrawer) {
                eventDrawer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:eventCell.bounds];
                UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 25, 44)];
                [eventDrawer addSubview:button];
            }

            eventDrawer.frame = eventCell.bounds;
            NSLog(@"X:%f  Y:%f  Width: %f  Height: %f", eventDrawer.bounds.origin.x, eventDrawer.bounds.origin.y, eventDrawer.bounds.size.width, eventDrawer.bounds.size.height);
            [eventCell.contentView addSubview:eventDrawer];
            [eventCell bringSubviewToFront:eventDrawer];
            eventDrawer.hidden = NO;
        }
```

Comment: I wanted to add the results of the NSLog print out as well. The X & Y values are 0:0 and the Width and Height values are 320:46 as they should be.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `eventDrawer.bounds = eventCell.bounds;` try `eventDrawer.frame = eventCell.bounds;`

The `bounds` of a view are viewed from inside, so the origin will be 0, 0. However the `frame` of a view is relative to it's superview, so the origin can differ from 0, 0.

Comment: I made the suggested change, however the UIView still does not show up.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set in your custom uiview's xib file set class `HZEventDrawerView` and change line

```
eventDrawer = (HZEventDrawerView *)[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HZEventDrawerView" owner:self options:nil][0];
```

On:

```
eventDrawer = [[HZEventDrawerView alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"HZEventDrawerView" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: My UIView's xib file already had the class set to HZEventDrawerView. When I use the initWithNibNamed: initializer Xcode fails to compile; I'm told "No visible @interface for 'HZEventDrawerView' declares the selector 'initWithNibNamed:bundle:'"

Comment: I believe you are assuming that my UIViews xib file class is a sub-class of UIViewController. It is currently a sub-class of UIView, which does not have that method.

Comment: As shown in my update, it would appear that it is not my XIB that is causing the issue. Even creating a UIView pragmatically and adding it to the cell doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The following line is the problem:

```
// Grab the selected cell and make sure it's an event cell
UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

You are retrieving a new cell from the UITableViewDataSource!
Instead, you should get the cell from the UITableView directly:

```
// Grab the selected cell and make sure it's an event cell
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks guest, I tried that however that does not fix the issue. When I invoke it using the old line, my cellForRowAtIndexPath: method implementation gets invoked and I can step through it with the debugger. When I do it as you suggested (I had tried this earlier today as well) the my break point never gets hit within the method. However, a UITableViewCell is returned. I'm not sure why my implementation never gets its breakpoint hit.

Comment: I should clarify, a UITableViewCell is returned, even though a break point is never hit. However the UIView does not display on the UITableViewCell either way. So I'm stumped.