# Is it possible to display UIView as UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitableview

How do we display the UIView as UITableViewCell? Is it possible to do this?
Please note, that I want to display the UIView AS A CELL, not OPEN THE UI VIEW when it is clicked, like what is mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296235/display-a-uiview-within-a-uitableviewcell-pragmatically) or other posts -- thus i think this is not a duplicate, since in most of the discussion, they are trying to show UIView when the UITableViewCell is clicked.

The reason why I want this, is because I am implementing my app in Accordion style. Thus, the desired functionality is, once the section is clicked, the row shows UIView (I am referring to indexPath section and row). I already have the accordion style working with pre-defined style cell (just label). But I am stuck on this case. This is what I mean by the accordion + uiview cell style : [picture](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/accordionview) (instead of map, i want to show my uiview, which contains button, image, label, etc).

I tried to do this inside my cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
  if (indexPath.section == 0)
  {
        if (indexPath.row == 1) // for row 1 of section 0
        {
           // yourView is my custom UIViewController
           [cell.contentView addSubview:(yourView.view)];
           [cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:(yourView.view)];
         }
  }
```

Maybe I am missing something?
I am new to iOS programming, so any help is really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered subclassing UITableViewCell and overriding a few methods? That way you can make a custom cell in Interface Builder.

Comment: Isn't it the same as what I tried in the code above? my 'yourView' is my custom UIView

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with following steps--

(1)First of all when your UITableView shows, return 0 for numberOfRowsInSection like--

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0;
}
```

(2)After that when your section clicked return your cell count(which you want)in numberOfRowsInSection and reload your UITableView.

(3)Configure your cell with your view as a subview in cell.
(4)When you want to hide your views in cells, just again follow the step (1) and (2).

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create Expandable and collapse tableviewcell

Use this below link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html